# DateTime Calculation Standardize

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, date-arithmetic

Is there any ways to standardize the date time format? 
Currently I am grabbing a data from database and they have sort my datetime into this format `2013-09-01 17:51:00` while the datetime calculation I grab are in this format `2013-9-3---02:18` Even that I might able to remove the `---` for the 2nd datetime but the format seem to be different from the first 1 and I guess that the reason I unable to perform the difference date time calculation.

Is there any recommendation or best way to convert or change the new grabbed datetime standardize exactly same as the first 1 so that I can perform some comparison before inserting into database?

Besides, I would like to calculate the difference between 2 datetime. I saw quite a lot of example online but most of it are calculating the date instead of date time ~ Any one guide me?

Comment: how are you doing your datetime calculation?

Comment: Can you give us examples for calculation datetimes that have double digit for month or day? Which is correct: `2013-11-25-02:18` or `2013-11-25---02:18` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$date = '2013-9-3---02:18';
$newdate = str_replace('---',' ',$date);
$phpdate = strtotime($newdate);
echo $mydate = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $phpdate );
echo "<br>";
echo $mysqldate = '2013-09-01 17:51:00';
echo "<br>";
$datetime1 = new DateTime($mydate);
$datetime2 = new DateTime($mysqldate);
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s');
```

Output

```
2013-09-03 02:18:00
2013-09-01 17:51:00 

00-0-1 08:27:0
```

Comment: Thansk for replying. Everything went smooth until the new DateTime part. I keep getting the errorstatus: 500 Internal Server Error. Any idea?

Comment: Finally I solved =D It's was some typo error. The spacing caused greatly error in PHP xD Thanks for the info bro =D

Comment: Besides, do u have any idea how change to interval back to minute only? Cause this part is used to define that if someone more than 10 min then will be marks as late =D.

Answer (score 1):

this will work for you

```
$phpdate = strtotime( $yourdate );
$mysqldate = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $phpdate );
```

just try above example.

and if you still not able to get your date. then you have to split date and time with `'-'` and reformat again.

Answer (score 1):

This should work :

#### Code:

```
$dateF = '2013-09-01 17:51:00';
$dateT = '2013-9-3---02:18';

$dtF = new DateTime($dateF);
$dtT = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y n j H:i', str_replace('-', ' ', $dateT));
```

Both dates are now in `DateTime` object, so now you can do anything with them :

#### Difference example :

```
$diff = $dtF->diff($dtT);
print_r($diff);
/*
    DateInterval Object
    (
        [y] => 0
        [m] => 0
        [d] => 1
        [h] => 8
        [i] => 27
        [s] => 0
        [invert] => 0
        [days] => 1
    )
*/
```

#### Compare example :

```
if ($dtF > $dtT) {
    echo 'Datetime in variable $dtF is bigger than $dtT';
}
```